# how to share internet between centos 7 with a Windows 10 through ethernet cable

Tags: windows

I have a win10 pc, it connected to the internet through a wireless usb card with a ip of (192.168.1.104), 
 I also set  ip(192.168.122.5) on its another ethernet interface card.

Another PC ( running centos 7) has ip (192.168.122.3). These two PCs can communicated through a 1000M switch. I can perform ssh and sftp successfully from win10 to centos7.

Now I want centos7 can access internet through win10, how to resovel this?

Comment: You question is: "How do I configure Microsoft's Windows, to forward the internet connection no another machine?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because is is about configuring Microsoft's Windows, and belongs on https://superuser.com/

Comment: I think it need to set the ip correctlyh in the centos 7 pc. it is not about how to set windows.

Comment: If the cestos is on seperate physical network to the internet connection, then it can not be configured to do it. You need to configure the bridge machine. You will need to configure it as a router; and a DHCP server onto the 2nd network. I don't even know if this i possible no MS-Windows home editions, you may need the server edition. However you should ask on superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Linux question really, it has to be done on the Windows side. Linux will just use the connection once it's available.

See the Microsoft article: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-10/f6dcac4b-5203-4c98-8cf2-dcac86d98fb9